# file_delete not deleting a file it returns xml response

Tags: files

When I call file_delete($file) to delete a file, it does not delete a file rather it returns the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result><file><node is_array="true"><item>1</item></node></file></result>
```

Comment: Post the XML again, it didn't go through.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result><file><node is_array="true"><item>1</item></node></file></result>

Comment: You will need to post more details about the site, setup and context in which you are trying to delete the file.

Comment: I am developing an android app where drupal is my back-end. In,one of my functionality I need to delete the file from a node. So, I hit the url (myDrupalSite/endpoint/file/fid) from android app with DELETE method. It return the xml response (I showed you earlier) with status 200 ok. But when I check my drupal site, the file has not been deleted.

Comment: It's much clearer now. Is there anything in the server logs or dblog? Sounds as if the permissions are not properly set. Also, did you try running it from Devel `devel/php`?